# ChartJS barchart tooltip with single serie

Tags: tooltip, bar-chart, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to plot a dataset to a bar chart. When I hover over the bars the name of the series with values will appear, so far so good.

However in my application it's possible that I get back a single group (one serie) from my database call. When I hover over the single bar the name of the serie and value is missing.

Preferred output would be the same as image 1 with only the single serie displayed. How to achieve this?

**code to watch for data and push to dataset for chart. No custom options are set.**

```
$scope.$watch("obtainedVouchers|groupBy:'voucherTitle'", function(collection){
                    if (!_.isEmpty(collection)) {
                        $scope.voucherChart_data = [];
                        $scope.voucherChart_label = ["Ingeleverde vouchers"];
                        $scope.voucherChart_series = [];
                        $scope.voucherChart_colours = ["#43A7BF", "#5ADFFF", "#163840", "#2D6F7F", "#51C8E5"];
                        for (var key in collection) {
                            var x = collection[key].length;
                            $scope.voucherChart_series.push(key);
                            $scope.voucherChart_data.push([x]);
                        }
                    }
                }, true);
```

**Multiple serie chart**

[image: chartjs good]

**data collection**
[image]

**Single serie chart**
[image: chartjs bad]

**data collection**

[image]

Comment: Post the code of your chart with datasets and options.

Comment: added code and screenshot of data to startpost

Comment: The trick was to use the multitooltip template which will display all the data from the dataset. Simple fix; use the following options object `$scope.barChartOptions = {tooltipTemplate : "<%= datasetLabel %>: <%= value %>"};`